# error while creating maven project to run on neo4j server

Tags: neo4j

How to resolve this exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to transition
>   component
>   'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.pagecache.PageCacheLifecycle@4b845428' from
>   STOPPED to SHUTTING_DOWN. Please see attached cause exception     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:559)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:200)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.shutdown(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:685)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:340)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:108)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:95)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:176)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:67)
>     at neo4jExamples.secondExample.main(secondExample.java:18) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot close the PageCache while
>   files are still mapped:   neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names (1
>   mapping)  at
>   org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache.close(MuninnPageCache.java:473)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.pagecache.PageCacheLifecycle.shutdown(PageCacheLifecycle.java:42)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:555)
>     ... 9 more

My code is:

```
package neo4jExamples;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;

public class secondExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GraphDatabaseService graphDb;
        Node firstNode;
        Node secondNode;
        Relationship relationship;

        graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("/var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db");
        registerShutdownHook( graphDb );

        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {

            firstNode = graphDb.createNode();
            firstNode.setProperty( "message", "Hello, " );
            secondNode = graphDb.createNode();
            secondNode.setProperty( "message", "World!" );

            relationship = firstNode.createRelationshipTo( secondNode, RelTypes.KNOWS );
            relationship.setProperty( "message", "brave Neo4j " );

            System.out.print( firstNode.getProperty( "message" ) );
            System.out.print( relationship.getProperty( "message" ) );
            System.out.print( secondNode.getProperty( "message" ) );


            tx.success();
        }

    }

    private static void registerShutdownHook(final GraphDatabaseService graphDb) {

            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    graphDb.shutdown();
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two causes here:

1. another java process is accessing some of the files, unless something other helps consider a `kill -9 <pid>`
2. double check the file permissions in your `graph.db` folder.